# how to generate all possible number combinations to check Fermat's last theorem in an efficient way

Tags: python-3.x, math, python-itertools

I am trying to write a short script in python3 to test Fermat's last theorem. While I can test individual sets, I'm curious how I could test "all", or a ton of numbers at once. I'm not sure how to approach this so my code examples of what I have tried are sparse.

How can i generate all possible number permutations for A B and C where each are >2? My first problem with my approach below is that lists on a 32bit system appear to be limited to around 5 million items.

```
def fermat(a, b, c, n):
    return a**n + b**n == c**n

def test_fermat():
    alist, blist, clist, nlist = [a for a in range(2, 5000000000)], [b for b in range(2, 5000000000)], [c for c in range(2, 5000000000)], [n for n in range(2, 5000000000)]
    mixed = itertools.product(alist,blist,clist,nlist)
    for item in mixed:
        a,b,c,n = item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3] 
        print(a,b,c,n)
        fermat(a,b,c,n)
```

Comment: you probably don't want to generate the lists or the matrix and hold it in memory. It's sufficient for you to add the results to memory which fulfill Fermat's theorem. Thus: use generators instead of lists for your input. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators You simply hit the memory limit of your OS / your machine. It's also sufficient to test it for a >= b, as addition is commutative.

Comment: Do you realize that this is both useless and hopeless ?

Comment: Andrew Wiles has arranged to make this easy and efficient: `def fermat(a, b, c, n): return False`, at least for n >= 3

Comment: Once you get an `a0` or `b0` which makes the left side > the right side, then you know that all `a>=a0 and b>=b0` for that `c` will also be false. Similar considerations apply on the right side.